# $y''=a\frac{y}{(y')^2+b},y(0)=0,y'(0)=c,\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can some solve the following equation or at least tell me how to approximate the result?
$$y''=a\frac{y}{(y')^2+b},y(0)=0,y'(0)=c,\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$$
I have no idea if it is an easy task, but for my level of math, I can't solve it and I need it for a project. Wolfram cannot give me an answer, at least without pro computation power. It tells me it is a second order non linear ODE. Thanks in advance

Comment: If Wolfram couldn't solve it, we probably can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be, at least, reduced to quadrature. Let $p=y'$; then the ODE can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=p\frac{dp}{dy}=\frac{ay}{p^2+b} &\implies \int (p^2+b)p\,dp=\int ay\,dy \\
& \implies \frac{p^4}{4}+\frac{bp^2}{2} = \frac{ay^2}{2}+C_1. \tag{1}
\end{align}
From the initial condition $y(0)=0, p(0)=y'(0)=c$ it follows that $C_1=\frac{c^4}{4}+\frac{bc^2}{2}$.

Solving $(1)$ for $p$ is straightforward, and we find
$$
p=\pm\sqrt{-b\pm\sqrt{(b+c^2)^2+2ay^2}}. \tag{2}
$$
The signs in $(2)$ must be chosen in such a way that $p(0)=c$ is satisfied. Thus, we have four cases to consider:
$$
p(y)=\begin{cases}
+\sqrt{-b+\sqrt{(b+c^2)^2+2ay^2}}&\text{if $b+c^2\geq0$ and $c\geq0$,} \\
+\sqrt{-b-\sqrt{(b+c^2)^2+2ay^2}}&\text{if $b+c^2<0$ and $c\geq0$,} \\
-\sqrt{-b+\sqrt{(b+c^2)^2+2ay^2}}&\text{if $b+c^2\geq0$ and $c<0$,} \\
-\sqrt{-b-\sqrt{(b+c^2)^2+2ay^2}}&\text{if $b+c^2<0$ and $c<0$.}
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$
Integrating $y'=p(y)$ we finally obtain
$$
x=\int_0^y\frac{du}{p(u)}, \tag{4}
$$
which yields the solution to the ODE in implicit form.